# C++ and Project Euler #3 Compilation Error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#import <cmath>
#import <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main {
    int a;
    for(int x = 600851475142; x>cmath::sqrt(600851475143); x--) {
        if (600851475143%x==0) { //is it a factor of 600851475143?
            if p(x) { //is it also a prime?
                cout << x;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool p(int n) {
    for(int x = n; x<cmath::sqrt(n)+1; x++) {
        if (n%x==0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is my code for project euler #3 (http://projecteuler.net/problem=3). I am relatively new to C++.

Basically my approach was to count down from 600851475143, test if the number was a factor of 600851475143 and then see if it was prime. If it was then return the number and exit.
However, when I compile my code I get the error:

```
error: function definition does not declare parameters
In function 'bool p(int)':
error: 'cmath' has not been declared
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What compiler are you using? It should be complaining about `#import` too, that's not standard C++. You've got a lot of basic and strange errors in there.

Comment: @Mat Yeah I come from a python background and I am self taught so most of this is just hacked together. I am using Sublime Text 2 on Mac so I am guessing G++

Comment: If you want to learn C++ properly, you might want to start with a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @Angew Ok that sounds like a good starting point, I'll look into it.

Comment: You really need to learn to search first.  There are a lot of answers already for project Euler and prime numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, it really seems you are at-least new to C++, if not to programming itself.

1) In C++, we use #include instead of #import

2) you need to declare a function before calling it.
Something like:

```
bool p(int n);
```

before main function

3) Parenthesis is missing in main function. Should be: 'int main() {'

4) You don't need cmath:: for sqrt. Write some thing like:
    (int) sqrt((double)600851475143)
This is because sqrt does not take integer in parameter

5) 'if p(x) {' should be 'if (p(x)) {'

6) for-loop in function is always increasing.

7) it's a good idea to calculate sqrt before for-loop instead of in for-loop.

8) Welcome to programming world!

Comment: Thanks, I am new to C++ and relatively new to programming in general. This helps a lot!

Comment: Made these changes, Here is my code #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

bool p(int n) {
 int limit = sqrt(n)+1;
 for(int x = n; x>limit; x++) {
  if (n%x==0) {
   return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}

int main () {
 int a;
 for(long x = 0; x<600851475143; x++) {
  if (600851475143%x==0) { //is it a factor?
   if (p(x)) {
    cout << x;
    return 0;
   }
  }
 }
}

Now I compile fine but I get a floating point exception when I run my program

Comment: in 6) I'm talking about for-loop in function 'p'.

Comment: Ok, made that x>limit, still getting the error @mraaz

Comment: It should be x-- instead of x++

Comment: Fixed that, still getting a floating point exception @mraaz

Comment: I think, you need a minor correction in your logic. Think about it. Also, for both square root calculations, try casting to double and back to int, like I stated it 4)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the *header* is `cmath`, but `sqrt` is in namespace `std`.

Also: you probably want to compute the square root before the loop, then test against that result:

```
bool p(int n) { 
    int limit = std::sqrt(n)+1;
    for (int x=n; x<limit; x++)
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok changed it to

#import <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main {
 int a;
 for(int x = 600851475143; x>0; x--) {
  if (600851475143%x==0) { //is it a factor?
   if p(x) {
    cout << x;
    return 0;
   }
  }
 }
}

//is it a prime?
bool p(int n) {
 int limit = std::sqrt(n)+1;
 for(int x = n; x<limit; x++) {
  if (n%x==0) {
   return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}

But it gives me the error
error: function definition does not declare parameters
In function 'bool p(int)':
error: 'sqrt' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: @picklebobdogflog Just try `sqrt` on its own.

Comment: `int main {` You need params for main.

Comment: Fixed a few things here and there. Now I am getting this - error: 'p' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @picklebobdogflog Declare it!

Comment: @alexrider p is my function. What do you mean declare it? (Sorry complete idiot programmer here)

Comment: How can you use `import` in C++ without an error?  Are you using a Microsoft bastardized C++?  Or are you programming in C#?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No I am using Sublime Text 2 which I think compiles with g++. I fixed that though